# is it possible to sum every three rows of a particular user oracle ? with count function or any other function

Tags: mysql, oracle

my table name is `AGENTWISEMONTHLYREPORT`and fields are `USER_ID` `MONTH_YEAR` and `NO_FO_TICKETS`

```
  USER_ID    MONTH_YEAR  NO_FO_TICKETS 
 iciseva00031   201706  8
 iciseva00031   201705  22
 iciseva00031   201704  29
 iciseva00031   201703  30
 iciseva00031   201702  26
 iciseva00031   201701  14
 iciseva00031   201612  14
 iciseva00031   201611  14
 iciseva00031   201610  34
 iciseva00031   201609  25
 iciseva00031   201608  109
 iciseva00031   201607  11
```

expected out put is as follows:

```
userid         sum(no_of_tickets)
iciseva00031   151
iciseva00031   60
```

those sum(no_of_tickets) are sum of every 3 rows. 
 can any one help me.

Comment: Can you also show us the expected output? Also, have you tried anything so far to solve the problem?

Comment: why it mysql and oracle? you need both?

Comment: thank you @ Giorgos Betsos  for the replay i edited it with expected out put

Comment: @ user7294900 any one of it is okay.

Comment: How do you get to 151 and 60 with the example given? What if number of rows is not a multiple of 3, which 3 will you take? Are you interested in quarters (jan-mar, apr-jun, ...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If grouping by quarter (3 months) is what you are after, then in Oracle SQL you could do this:

```
select   user_id, 
         floor(to_number(month_year)/100) year,
         1 + floor((mod(to_number(month_year), 100) - 1) / 3) quarter, 
         sum(no_fo_tickets) sum_tickets
from     mytable
group by user_id, 
         floor(to_number(month_year)/100),
         1 + floor((mod(to_number(month_year), 100) - 1) / 3)
order by 1, 2 desc, 3 desc;
```

Output would be like:

```
   user_id   | year | quarter | sum_tickets
-------------+------+---------+------------
iciseva00031 | 2017 |    2    |    59
iciseva00031 | 2017 |    1    |    70
iciseva00031 | 2016 |    4    |    62
... etc
```

Comment: sir i want only last four quarters , how can i achieve it.

Comment: You can use `row_number() over` to get a row number per user_id, and then limit in an outer query on that number (<= 4). Please ask a new question if you need help, but with that information you should be able to find many similar questions and answers.